# Running Xcode target from command line

Tags: xcode

I am new to running unit tests using Catch.

I am using the Catch to run unit tests in my Xcode project. I have added a target to my project which includes my Catch files and tests cases. Selecting that target and running from Xcode runs fine. I am now trying to get it to run from the command line which will be the way it is run from Jenkins. I have a shell script that contains:

```
xcodebuild clean install
xcodebuild -target TestApp  -configuration “Debug”  -sdk iphonesimulator7.1   CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=TestBuild ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO
```

The result is:

```
** INSTALL SUCCEEDED **

Build settings from command line:
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = TestBuild
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator7.1

--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Configuration “Release” is not in the project. Building default configuration.

=== BUILD TARGET CreativeSDKTest OF PROJECT CreativeSDKImage WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Release) ===

Check dependencies

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
```

But the application doesn’t launch in the simulator. Maybe I’m not seeing the obvious but from all the docs I’ve read, this should launch the application.

Comment: BTW, I've tried adding the line: ./TestBuild/CreativeSDKTest.app/CreativeSDKTest but I get this as a result:  dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
  Referenced from: /Users/mscarafo/mscarafo_mscarafo-osx_278/ImageSDK.git/CreativeSDK/source/elements/image/build/./TestBuild/CreativeSDKTest.app/CreativeSDKTest
  Reason: image not found
./unit_test.sh: line 10: 65751 Trace/BPT trap: 5       ./TestBuild/CreativeSDKTest.app/CreativeSDKTest

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to tell `xcodebuild` to test the project:

```
xcodebuild clean install
xcodebuild -target TestApp  -configuration “Debug”  -sdk iphonesimulator7.1   CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=TestBuild ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO clean test
```

(See the end of the last command)

EDIT: In fact you probably don't even need the first command and just the second will do.

Comment: Thanks for the response but including the clean test results in this:

Comment: ** CLEAN SUCCEEDED **

=== BUILD TARGET CreativeSDKTest OF PROJECT CreativeSDKImage WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Release) ===

Check dependencies
unsupported build action 'test'

** TEST FAILED **

Comment: What's the output of `xcodebuild -list` (run from the same directory where the `.xcodeproj` is?

Comment: Remember I'm am using Catch as a unit test frame work, not XCTest.